# XML - Replace Node if exists on Android

Tags: android, xml, node.js

I have this kind of code for adding new `Node` in my XML file.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 200) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            int position = data.getIntExtra("position", 0);
            HashMap<String, String> intentmap = (HashMap<String, String>) data.getSerializableExtra("taskItems");
            taskItems.set(position, intentmap);

            InputSource inputSource = null;
            try {
                inputSource = new InputSource(openFileInput(filename));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String uuid = taskItems.get(position).get("uuid");
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            try {
                Node taskNode = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//task[@uuid='" + uuid + "']", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE);
                Document document = taskNode.getOwnerDocument();
                //Füge neue Zeile ein
                Node noteNode = document.createElement("task_note");
                noteNode.setTextContent(taskItems.get(position).get("task_note"));
                taskNode.appendChild(noteNode);
                //Speichere Datei
                Source input = new DOMSource(document);
                Result output = new StreamResult(openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(input, output);
            } catch (XPathExpressionException | FileNotFoundException | TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

What if the `Element` `task_note` already exists?

I searched my File in the private App directory and saw, that there was about 20 `task_note`.
How can I change my Code to replace the `Node` if already exist.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

Instead of using:

```
taskNode.appendChild(noteNode);
```

I'm using:

```
taskNode.replaceChild(oldNode,noteNode);
```